# Match Integer and float with only single or 2 digits in python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I dealing with a string that consists of integers and float values and also other numeric stuff. I am interested to pick up only 1 or 2 digits integer or float numbers using regex in python.
The digits of my interest could be
at the start of the string
in between the string
at the end of the string

A sample string is given below

```
1 2 years of experience in dealing with 20-20-20 and python3 and 5 development and maintenance of 500.
```

I am interested in 1,2 and 5. And not in 500 or 20-20-20

The regex I am trying is

```
((?:^|\s)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(?:$|\s))|((?:^|\s)\d{1,2}(?:$|\s))
```

but it doesn't detect 2 and 5. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something like this: [`(?:^|\s)(-?\d{1,2})(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/67gNis/1) ?

Comment: @Jan it doesnt match float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
(?:^| )([+-]?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)(?= |$)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(?:^| )`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching either the start of line or a space.
- **`([+-]?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)`** - Represents first capturing group capturing all the one or 2 digit floating numbers(negative or positive). If you want to restrict the decimal digits; you can make your required changes here. Something like `([+-]?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{DESIRED_LIMIT})?)`.
- **`(?= |$)`** - Represents a positive look-ahead matching the numbers which are either followed by a space or represents end of the line.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/67gNis/4)

**Sample implementation in python:**

```
import re

regex = r"(?:^| )([+-]?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)(?= |$)"
# If you require for number between 0 to 20. (?:^| )([+-]?(?:[0-1]?\d|20)(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\s|$)

test_str = "1 2 years of experience in dealing with 20-20-20 and python3 and 5 development and maintenance of 500. -2 is the thing. 20.566"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
# outputs: ['1', '2', '5', '-2', '20.566']
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/BkjgAG-RL)

Comment: Thanks to @Jan and his comment which helped in writing this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you suggest the answer to detect digits only between 0 to 20. I replaced \d with [0-9]|1[1-9] to achieve this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: it worked perfectly @Mandy8055. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: seen, and bookmarked the tool. I deleted my comment